# Can a single pointer be initialized in a function and if so how?

Tags: c, function, pointers, initialization

I have been given this function prototype `void create_smth(smth* s)`  and it is asked that this function **creates, initializes and returns** a smth variable. Is this even possible? To my knowledge I would need a double pointer to do such a thing.
What I am doing in this function is

```
s=(smth*)malloc(sizeof(smth));
```

This is probably the mistake.

In my main I have tried

```
smth* smth1=NULL;
create_smth(smth1);
```

and

```
smth smth1;
create_smth(&smth1);
```

but my code keeps crashing (Segmentation fault; core dump). I am starting to wonder if it is an instructors mistake but feel stupid to ask him straight up but the excercise requires what I stated above.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: You *probably* need `smth *smth1;
create_smth(&smth1);` But without [mcve] no one can tell for sure.

Comment: @JamesTheProg A function that has the return type void returns nothing.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow probably means as in returns via allocating memory. That is besides the point.

Comment: Please [edit] show your _verbatim_ code especially the one that is crashing. Then we can tell you more.

Comment: JamesTheProg, Both good answers [KR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69666656/2410359) [y](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69666557/2410359) below imply a `uncreate_smth()` or the like is warranted.  If the creation/initialization happens in a helper function, so should the freeing of resources happen in a helper function - even if that function is a no-op.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like instructor's mistake to me.  You are correct that the `void create_smth(smth* s)` prototype cannot return a value, either in the traditional `return` sense (it is `void`), or using a double pointer.  The only two ways to do this:

```
smth* creat_smth()
{
  smth* mySmth = malloc(sizeof *mySmth);
  // check malloc return valid pointer, initialize fields with mySmth->
  return mySmth;
}

int main(void)
{
  smth* smth1 = creat_smth();
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

or

```
void creat_smth(smth** mySmth)
{
  *mySmth = malloc(sizeof **mySmth);
  // check malloc returned valid pointer, initialize fields with (*mySmth)->
}

int main(void)
{
  smit* smth1;
  creat_smth(&smth1);
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The translation to english as "Return" probably didn't help you guys. He probably means "Returns" as in "assigns the new value via this memory reference"

Comment: @JamesTheProg not sure I follow. There's only two function prototypes I'm aware of that can allocate memory and have it persist outside the function. I've detailed both of those in my answer, neither of those match the prototype you've been given. The exception being if `smth` hides a pointer via `typedef`, which is bad practice (but certainly needs to be added to your question if that's the case).

Comment: `smth* smth1 = creat_smth();` does have an advantage over `creat_smth(&smth1);`:  [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization).  Object lives in limbo until `creat_smth(&smth1)`.

Answer (score 4):

It’s worth asking your instructor for clarification. That said, it’s at least somewhat common to have functions that follow the pattern `int init_smth(smth *x)` — but note the name: such functions are usually called `init_•`, not `create_•` (because it *doesn’t* create the storage for this object, it just fills it).

This makes sense when it’s expected that stack-allocating the struct is the right thing to do. Instead of using `malloc`, the user would pass a pointer to a locally allocated structure:

```
smth my_smth;
init_smth(&my_smth);
```

And inside `init_smth` some moderately complex initialisation would take place (but again *without `malloc`*: the memory for the object is already allocated).

However, even then it’s more common for the function to return a status code indicating success (hence the return type `int` in my prototype above).